# where is .bash_profile in cloudera?

Tags: linux, cloudera

I am unable to locate .bash_profile in cloudera machine. can anyone tell me what command do I use to find this file ?

i have tried

```
find -name ".bash_profile"
```

and nothing happen I just don't understand why. new to cloudera and linux command

Answer (score 0):

.bash_profile might not exist by default then it's just a matter of creating it. Read useful information about .bash_profile & .profile here: https://superuser.com/questions/278433/whats-the-difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile-and-when-do-you-config